# Keep the original format when adding audio-filter, auto-detect format from original file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Multiple users upload different kind of videos and I do not save the format of these videos, just the codecs. ffmpeg detects the video and audio codec when needed and it was all good till today. I was adding a audio normalization step. How to make ffmpeg auto choose a container format based on codecs? It seems ffmpeg will choose the output audio codec based on the format specified. Can I ask it to stick to original format and codec whatever it was?

```
ffmpeg -y -i /mnt/tmp/asjkdh39 -c:v copy -af "volume=10.7dB" /mnt/tmp/0540hsl
```

For the above command, I get an error:

```
[NULL @ 0x9214a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '/mnt/tmp/0540hsl'
```

Comment: Not possible, At best, you can run `ffprobe file -hide_banner -show_entries format=format_name -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v quiet` and then supply `-f value` after `-af ...`. BTW, volume doesn't normalize, use dynaudnorm for that.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya for pointing out `dynaaudnorm`. I am trying it out. Although in my case, I need to normalize audio across multiple videos rather than through the duration of a video. As such, I am using `volumedetect` to find negative max_volume and then increasing it by that much.

Comment: Since there are no more solutions, you can add your comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, At best, you can run

```
ffprobe file -hide_banner -show_entries format=format_name -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v quiet
```

and then supply `-f value` after `-af ....`.